# How to track current URL changes in service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

I want to track user's activities in my PWA. Is it possible to send a request to my server on each site impression with current URI?

Scenario: User opens PWA -> request with current URI.
User opens a subpage -> send request with current URI.

My example service-worker.js:

```
var cacheName = 'weatherPWA-step-6-2';
var filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/scripts/app.js',
  '/styles/inline.css',
  '/images/clear.png',
  '/images/cloudy-scattered-showers.png',
  '/images/cloudy.png',
  '/images/fog.png',
  '/images/ic_add_white_24px.svg',
  '/images/ic_refresh_white_24px.svg',
  '/images/partly-cloudy.png',
  '/images/rain.png',
  '/images/scattered-showers.png',
  '/images/sleet.png',
  '/images/snow.png',
  '/images/thunderstorm.png',
  '/images/wind.png'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        if (key !== cacheName) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Fetch', e.request.url);
  console.log("Url", Client.url);
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: you can just listen to the `hashchange` event on window and do whatever you want.

Comment: @JPrakash: Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question should probably be phrased like this:

How can I track the page views in my analytics package when files are being served from cache?

This is a great question because you are definitely adjusting the activity.

If you only track activity based on your server logs then you will need to perform a network request each time. This is a bit inefficient and old school IMO. But if it is your way to track activity build a way to deal with it. You will need to build a sort of faux AJAX way to update the logs. Of course you could use that to also keep your cache fresh, the stale while revalidate strategy.

If you are using a service like Google Analytics then you would programmatically trigger the traffic. The nice thing about these services is you wont need to change anything to trigger them logging activity because they measure from the UI, not the server.

If you allow activity when the consumer is offline then you need to queue up the activity and replay it once they go back online. This is where the background sync API will be useful once it has broad support.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have more questions and clarifications.